Unresolved reference: registerForActivityResult in FlutterFragmentActivity
I have been getting this error in my MainActivity.kt for almost a week now, and still haven't found a solution that work.
The error is "Unresolved reference: registerForActivityResult" with registerForActivityResult underlined in red. It's the only error there is found in my build. I'm using FlutterFragmentActivity as this is the closest solution i could get, but still not moving the error away.
I have also added the latest activity and fragment dependencies in build.gradle but is still getting the same error. Is there any other steps that I have missed out on apart from adding dependencies and using FlutterFragmentActivity? These are the only two steps that I have done so far. This is the code where im using registerForActivityResult. I put this before configureFlutterEngine, inside FlutterFragmentActivity
val activityLauncher = registerForActivityResult(SomeContract()) { result: SomeResponse<Unit> ->
        // Check if the result is a success
        when (result) {
            is SomeResponse.Success -> {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Done!.")
                // Handle the success case if needed
            }
            is SomeResponse.Failed -> {
                Log.e("MainActivity", "Trigger failed: ${result.rspMsg}")
                // Handle the error case if needed
            }
        }
    }

I'm using flutter version 3.19.0, build:gradle 8.7.3, kotlin 1.9.0. Below are the dependencies added in my build.gradle
 implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0'
 implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.7.0'
 implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.9.3"
 implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.8.5"
 implementation 'io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0'

I've duplicated the solution from here but it's giving me null error if i use ComponentActivity. Here's the code:
fun launchSomeOperation(result: MethodChannel.Result) {

//        val componentActivity = (activity as? ComponentActivity)
//            ?: throw IllegalStateException("Activity must extend ComponentActivity to use registerForActivityResult")

        val resultLauncher =
            ComponentActivity().registerForActivityResult(SomeContract()) { result: SomeResponse<Unit> ->
                when (result) {
                    is SomeResponse.Success -> {
                        Log.d("MainActivity", "Operation successful.")
                        // Handle the success case if needed
                    }

                    is SomeResponse.Failed -> {
                        Log.e("MainActivity", "Operation failed or cancelled: ${result.rspMsg}")
                        // Handle the error case if needed
                    }
                }
            }
        
    }



private fun triggerOperation(c: String) {
        val operationRequest = SomeCustomRequest.CustomOperation(c)

        activityLauncher.launch(operationRequest)
 }


This question is similar to: How to use registerForActivityResult in Flutter's MainActivity?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I have made an edit to my question @Robin
